# Google Sheets Regex to find left most alternation match

Tags: regex, google-sheets

How can I adjust this regex to pick only one match in an alternation phrase please. I'm using the Google Sheets REGEXEXTRACT function to collect parts of a string. I have almost all conditions covered by using alternation - except one, the one in which the source string includes more than one of the alternation matches.

A simple test example, in B1:B4 I have.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"([^\d]*)\s?(?:vs|bc)")
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"([^\d]*)\s?(?:vs|bc)")
=REGEXEXTRACT(A3,"([^\d]*)\s?(?:bc|vs)")
=REGEXEXTRACT(A4,"([^\d]*)\s?(?:bc|vs)")
```

(note the inverted bc|vs alternation in B3 & B4)

In A1:A4 I have

```
oiu tgi vs ghj bc fgh
de nbv the vs ghj fgh
ghj YHTF bc fgh
iii iii kji bc fgh vs oiu
```

The results I want in B1:B4

```
oiu tgi
de nbv the
ghj YHTF
iii iii kji
```

The problem is the engine (quite correctly) matches both alternation phrases and extracts everything to the left of the last match (rightmost) in the source string. Not what I want.  The various text lengths between the alternation matches is random. Is my whole approach wrong?

The results I actually get in B1:B4 are:

```
oiu tgi vs ghj 
de nbv the 
ghj YHTF 
iii iii kji bc fgh
```

As the number of rows in the real data is many thousands I obviously want a universal regex for all variants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works

```
=ArrayFormula(regexreplace(A1:A4, "(\s(?:bc|vs).+$)",))
```

Comment: Thx JPV. Perfect. Marked as a correct answer (bit late, sorry).

Comment: btw. my question related specifically to regex in Google Sheets. For those following, the link provided by W Stribizew did not provide an answer, just a clue.